# It says I am inserting too many values in my columns when I am not?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am creating a login menu and I put in the details:

```
Username:test2
Email:Test2
Password: testPassword
Confirm Password: testPassword
```

The confirm password must be the same as password for it to go into the database so it would be one value

[image]

then i get the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'test2test2testPassword'.
> There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.'

Could someone help?

Comment: Take a look at your generated SQL. It probably looks something like `... VALUES(usernameuser@domain.compassword)`. You forgot to put any commas in, or quote your values. In fact, you shouldn't be constructing SQL queries like this anyway -- ever heard of SQL injection? Use a parameterised query.

Comment: Secondly, please put code in `code sections` not images of code.

Comment: If you had actually looked at the SQL you have generated, it would have been very obvious where the problem is.

Comment: You should also dispose your connection and command with a `using`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems in your code:

1. You should use parameters in your queries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0
2. The values should be comma separated:

```
insert into RegisterTable(RegUsername, RegEMail, RegPassword)
                   Values('test2','test2','testPassword')
```

3. Never store unhashed passwords in your database. See [Best way to store password in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)

Comment: And, storing passwords without hashing them first is an invitation to cybercreeps to hack your users.

Answer (score 2):

The comments covered it pretty well but you are missing seperation between your values in your query
on top of that you should not trust user entered text and use it directly in to queries

you should used paramatized commands like this

```
var checkCount =
    new SqlCommand("insert into [TableName] (id, othercolumn) VALUES(@id, @otherColumn)",
                    conn);
checkCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
checkCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@otherColumn", otherColumn);
```